# How to calculate an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I wonder how the integral

$$\int_{-1}^1 \! \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \! \int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2-x^2}} \! 1 \, dz  \, dy  \, dx $$

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know spherical coordinates?

Comment: Can you tell from the limits of integration what shape region we're looking at here? This is a volume calculation of a familiar geometric shape.

Comment: @DanielFischer i heared something like that, but i would like to avoid using them(If possible)

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I know that i could calculate it using the formula of the sphere: $\frac{4}{3}\pi$ . But i would like to calculate it more elemental (If possible)

Comment: @Xtk The most elementary way to evaluate the integral is by switching to spherical coordinates. Yes, you could do it other ways, but it is pointlessly tedious. You should learn they are useful sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this without geometry or spherical coordinates, here's what it looks like:

$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 \! \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \! \int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2-x^2}} \! 1 \, dz  \, dy  \, dx &= \int_{-1}^1 \! \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \! \sqrt{1-y^2-x^2}  \, dy  \, dx \\
&= \int_{-1}^1 \! \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \! \sqrt{(1-x^2)-y^2}  \, dy  \, dx
\end{align}$

At this point, you can do the change of variables $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}\sin t$, which gives us $dy=\sqrt{1-x^2}\cos t \, dt$, and changes the limits on the inside integral:

$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 \! \int_0^{\pi/2} \! \sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-\sin^2 t)}\sqrt{1-x^2}\cos t  \, dt  \, dx &= \int_{-1}^1 \! (1-x^2) \int_0^{\pi/2} \! \sqrt{\cos^2 t}\cos t  \, dt  \, dx \\
&= \int_{-1}^1 \! (1-x^2) \int_0^{\pi/2} \! \cos^2 t  \, dt  \, dx \\
&=\int_{-1}^1 \! (1-x^2) \frac{\pi}{4}  \, dx \\
&=\frac{\pi}{4} \int_{-1}^1 \! (1-x^2) \, dx \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^1 \! (1-x^2) \, dx \\
&=\frac{\pi}2\cdot\frac23 = \frac{\pi}3
\end{align}$

Is that pretty much what you're looking for?

Comment: Thats what I want. Thank you very much!